# Android: Convert Text Input to ASCII and print it as a string

Tags: java, android, converters

This is my code

```
EditText textExtract = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textInput);
    String textInput = textExtract.getText().toString();
    TextView textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
```

I am taking input from the user and storing it in String **textInput**.
Now, how do  I convert the String **textInput** to a String of ASCII values which I want to print using the textView textOut.

For example,

```
Input = "abcd"
Output = 979899100
```

Comment: Look at `String.getBytes(Charset)` to get the bytes - but you'll then need to convert the bytes back into a string...

Comment: I gave that a try. For printing, I converted it back to string using `.toString()` and it gave out the output same as the input.

Comment: Sounds like you called `toString` on the wrong thing then - if you called it on a `byte[]` you'd have got an output of `[B@abcdef10` or similar. But that would be a start. Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static long toAscii(String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String ascString = null;
    long asciiInt;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        sb.append((int)s.charAt(i));
        char c = s.charAt(i);
    }
    ascString = sb.toString();
    asciiInt = Long.parseLong(ascString);
    return asciiInt;
}



String outputText = toAscii(textInput).toString();
textOut.setText(outputText);
```

This could be helpful for your case

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova: You convert the string (abcd) into Dec (979899100), but if i want to convert string (abcd) into hex (61626364), how would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a character to ascii by casting the char to an int for example

```
char c = 'A';
int ascii = (int) c;
```

To convert a whole string, iterate over the array of all chars. You can get the Array using `"Hello".getCharArray();`

That would look like this:

```
String input = "Hello World";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for(char c : chars) 
    sb.append((int) c);
String output = sb.toString();
```

Here a StringBuilder is used to chain the single numbers together, which is better than using .concat() on Strings multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle into the string and for every char convert it to a Character.toString ((char) i), store the result in array and print it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String str = textView1.getText().toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        sb.append((int)c);
    BigInteger mInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
    textView2.setText(mInt.toString());
```